# Is there any way to make a window fixed?

Tags: java, window, size

Is there any way to make a window fixed so that the user can't change the window size in java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Frame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) class (and its child [`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class for Swing) there is a [`setResizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable(boolean)) method which will set whether or not a `Frame` can be resized or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
JFrame myFrame= new JFrame();
myFrame.setResizable(false);
```

My solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Frame class, there is a setResizable method which will set whether or not a Frame can be resized or not. So, if you want to fixed window than just write setResizable(false).